# App Store - Before you can submit this app for review, an Admin must provide information about the app’s privacy practices in the App Privacy section

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Account holder updated the App Privacy Section of App Store but still it is showing me the above error when i go to submit App for Review.

Is there any other info or process which account holder need to enter in App Privacy??

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The Apple has change some terms for the Privacy Policy while submitting the new/updated app to the store.

The developer has to answer some question about the data collection like what data is being collected in the app? Does those data used for tracking purpose?, etc.

You can find the **App Privacy** option at left side under **General** tag.

[image]

When you click on get started the you will see the below image where you need to give the answer for some questions.

[image]

Once you fill out the all the questionaries. You will see the similar page like below but based on the questionaries you fill.

[image]

Comment: I do not see the App Privacy screen in your screenshot, but rather the old version with their simple privacy policy. Not sure how to get it to show the Product Page Preview section...any ideas?